# How to call Magento block in phtml template?

Tags: php, magento, content-management-system, block

i need to display some more links in footer. i created those links in magento admin as static blocks (id = sample_links ).

and then i added following code page.xml file

```
<reference name="foot_lnk">  
<block type="cms/block" name="sample_block" before="-">
      <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>sample_links</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

i called this one in footer.phtml as,

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('foot_lnk') ?>
```

but it does not display the CMS static block content. what is the issue?.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reference is the block previously defined that you want your block to be inside, e.g.:

```
<reference name="footer">
  <block type="cms/block" name="sample_links">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>sample_links</block_id></action>
  </block>
</reference>
```

Then

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('sample_links') ?>
```

Comment: its working thanks. already i have default footer links in <default> tag. i added block codes 

<block type="cms/block" name="sample_links">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>sample_links</block_id></action>
  </block>
with in it.

Answer (score 20):

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my_static_block_name')->toHtml()
```

Comment: yes i used above one it's working. but i need to display using XML like above.

Answer (score 8):

You can call a statick block like:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```

And call a block like:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sidebar/left')->setTemplate('bannerslider/left.phtml')->tohtml(); ?>
```

Visit [magevn.com](http://magevn.com/how-to-use-a-magento-block) to see more usecase to use block in magento.

Comment: more complete answer, thanks for the added info, makes a google search much  more complete :)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to bother with XML, same as swapnesh's answer, I'm just making it clearer for the php noobs out there (like me)

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('your_identifier')->toHtml() ?>
```

your_identifier is the code you decide to use when creating your block in CMS > Blocks > Create New Block, second line called "Identifier"

Comment: Well, you should have edited his answer to add precisions, then, instead of posting an almost identical one.

Answer (score 0):

change  your reference name to **footer**

like

```
<reference name="footer">
```

then it will work.