# Magento - where to add include files

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I need to include a php snippet to a few `.phtml` template files e.g. `<?php include("foo.php") ?>`:

[image]

Where is the common place to add `foo.php`? Can I just create a folder called "partials" in the root dir or is there already a special place for include files?

Comment: you create block files that reference a template, than call it in relevant xml file - also as an FYI, all support for Magento 1.x stops this november

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs, thanks! I am new to magento, should I just create a random new block file in "app/local..." and use it with `$helper = Mage::helper('foo_bar');` ?
Is there a guide on how to to this, please help.

Comment: It would be great if you could make me an example which adds "hello world" or show me where I can inform about this. Im not sure what exactly I have to search for in google.

Comment: if I could remember fully I would (moved on to Magento2 now and it's replaced my Magento1 knowledge xD) this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10647650/how-to-call-magento-block-in-phtml-template